# read from stdin script in heredoc script piped to `sh`

Tags: shell, pipe, stdin

This works as expected

```
$> cat ./readfromstdin.sh
echo reading
cat /dev/stdin

$> echo hello | ./readfromstdin.sh
reading
hello
```

I am trying to achieve something similar without a temporary file. My first attempt was

```
echo hello | (echo cat /dev/stdin|sh)
```

which did not work. With a heredoc it did not work either (though I am not sure what the right syntax would be:

```
echo hello | (cat << EOF | sh
cat /dev/stdin
EOF)
pipe cmdsubst pipe heredoc>
```

Is it possible to read from stdin using a script piped to the shell?

Comment: I think you are looking for `echo hello | sh -c 'echo reading; cat /dev/stdin'` ?

Comment: It might help if you explained why you want to do this. This feels like it could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101), so explaining what your final objective is might get you more useful answers. For example, why don't you just use `read` instead of fiddling with `/dev/stdin`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you describe relatively easily by piping to a subshell:

```
$ echo hello | ( echo reading; cat /dev/stdin )
reading
hello
```

I admit I can't really imagine any use case for this though. Why not just do:

```
$ echo hello | ( echo reading; read var; echo "$var")
reading
hello
```

That way you have the stdin contents saved as a variable and can manipulate them at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'world' |  { echo 'hello'; cat }
hello
world
```

There's no need to explicitly give `/dev/stdin` to `cat` as that is what `cat` operates on by default if no other operands are given.

In your own code, it looks as if you want to pass a *command* rather than a string to output. That's how I interpret the presence of `sh` in the code anyway. I'm not entirely sure you need that though.

The problem you're having with doing that is due to feeding the script to `sh` on its standard input. The standard input will thus be reserved for commands, so piping a string into it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to access stdin, from a subshell, which has already been passed a command over stdin, which references stdin passed from the parent process?

That's a mouthfull - do you mean something like this:

```bsh
$ cat ~/.tmp/test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

echo i am stdin from pipe | {
    echo '0</dev/fd/100 cat -' | sh -x

} 100<&0
```

```bsh
$ ~/.tmp/test.sh 
+ cat -
i am stdin from pipe
```

- `echo i am stdin from pipe` is redirected to fd `100<&0` so as to not to lose the reference
- `'0</dev/fd/100 cat -'` is passed as a string to the stdin of `sh -x` which evals and executes
- the stdin reference `/dev/fd/100` is redirected to `/dev/stdin` for the process `cat -`, which writes to stdout the string `i am stdin from pipe`

Just to be clear, don't ever do this ^^.